# how to resolve SQL Error: ORA-14411

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to alter a table by adding a column, but it's giving the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE TUSER
  ADD CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(250)

SQL Error: ORA-14411: The DDL cannot be run concurrently with other DDLs
```

How to unlock the resource which is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this:

```
ALTER TABLE TUSER
  RENAME TO new_TUSER;


ALTER TABLE new_TUSER
  ADD (CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(250));


ALTER TABLE new_TUSER
  RENAME TO TUSER;
```

Answer (score 3):

A little old question, but found another solution.
Looks like this error also can occur due to deadlock in the table (many users working on the same table, etc.)

So you can kill sessions via then menu: Tools --> Monitor Sessions --> Choose selection.

There you should see a table with all running commands, the command, the user and more.

Right click --> Kill session.

[Link to Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/monitoring.htm#ADMQS244)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! It should be noted that you need to connect as SYS in order for this to work

Answer (score 2):

My colleague had the same problem in the Oracle SQL developer, he executed a DDL statement and the machine was taking forever. Somehow it was not reachable, and after some time it responded again. No idea what happened and my colleague called me for help.

After the machine answered again he tried to execute the same statement which returned an ORA-14411.

The solution was to just click rollback in the same prompt-frame, and after that we were able to re-execute the same statement successfully.